# WCF Stream/Message size

Tags: wcf

I have a streamed WCF service. In one operation, I receive a file, for upload purposes.
If I try to do something like this

```
request.FileContent.Length
```

Then I receive an OperationNotSupported exception. That's Ok.
But how could I get the file size without actually transfering it entirely?
I know I could send this information along with the call, as a Header, but I don't want to go this way.

If WCF is able to limit the request size trough maxReceiveMessageSize. How can I use the same information to check the message/stream size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can't know the size of a byte stream without reading it all and counting the bytes, unless there is data at the start of the stream which tells you how many bytes there are in the entire stream, or some other out-of-band way to communicate the length of the stream, such as in the WCF message headers. You will have to go with the Header approach if you want to know the size without reading the stream.

The WCF maxReceiveMessageSize works by counting the bytes as they are received and throwing an exception if the limit is exceeded... it doesn't know the stream length either, and can't pre-emptively prevent the message being received without first reading the maximum allowed number of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

> But how could I get the file size without actually transfering it entirely? I know I could send this information along with the call, as a Header, but I don't want to go this way.

You're going to have to send the size of the byte stream down the pipe first there is no other way. (if there was some inbuilt way thats all it would be doing anyway)

It doesn't add much complexity to prepend it to the stream:

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("somefile.txt");
stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((Int32)bytes.Length), 0,  4);
stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

and then on the other side when reading the stream:

```
byte[] fileLengthBytes =new byte[4];
stream.Read(fileLengthBytes, 0, 4);
int length = BitConverter.ToInt32(fileLengthBytes, 0);
//you know the size of the file now, log it or show the user
var fileBytes = new byte[length];
stream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
```

this is only an *example* - you may not want to create a `byte[]` buffer if your stream is large.